# Comparar se o valor de uma variável, é o mesmo que valor já salvo no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, adonisjs, knex.js

Usando **Java Script, NodeJS, AdonisFramework, Mysql, Lucid ORM**

Preciso verificar *comparar* se o valor enviado pelo cliente através da API é o mesmo presente no meu banco de dados.
Preciso verificar se a variável **token** passada pelo usuário na requisição, é exatamente a mesma que de **passwordResetToken** que é um *campo de uma tabela do meu banco de dados Mysql*

Acredito que deva ser alguma função do *lucid ORM*, que compare se os valores são iguais.
Ou até mesmo montar um *query builder* para tal confirmação.

Ainda não obtive sucesso, mesmo tentando de diversas formas diferentes.
Se alguém sacar dessa sintaxe ou função de deve ser usada e puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já!

Atenciosamente Guilherme Henrique

```js
 async resetPassword({ request, response }) {
    const { email, token, password } = request.body;
    

   
    //ERROR MYSQL KNEX-LUCID SINTAXE METHOD
    try {
     

      const user = await User.findBy("email", email);
      const verificationToken = await User.findBy("passwordResetToken");

      //CHECK IF EMAIL IN DB IS VALID
      if (user == null) {
        return response
          .status(400)
          .send({ error: "An existing valid E-mail must be sent" });
      }

      //CHECK IF TOKEN IS VALID-FEATURE
      if (token != verificationToken) {
        return response.status(400).send({
          error: "Your token is wrong, please try again with a valid token",
        });
      }

      if (token == verificationToken) {
        user.merge({
          //passwordResetToken: token,
          password: password,
        });

        await user.save();

        response.status(200).json({
          message: "Password changed successfully",
        });
      }
  

      user.merge({
        //passwordResetToken: token,
        password: password,
      });

      await user.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400).send({ error: "Cannot reset password, try again" });
    }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/103212/guillerbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

```js
async resetPassword({ request, response }) {
    const { email, token, password } = request.body;
    
   
    try {
      const user = await User.findBy("email", email);
      const verificationToken = user.passwordResetToken;

      

      console.log(verificationToken);

      //CHECK IF EMAIL IN DB IS VALID
      if (user == null) {
        return response
          .status(400)
          .send({ error: "An existing valid E-mail must be sent" });
      }

      //CHECK IF TOKEN IS VALID-FEATURE
      if (token != verificationToken) {
        return response.status(400).send({
          error: "Your token is wrong, please try again with a valid token",
        });
      }

      if (token == verificationToken) {
        user.merge({
          //passwordResetToken: token,
          password: password,
        });

        await user.save();

        response.status(200).json({
          message: "Password changed successfully",
        });
      }

      user.merge({
        
        password: password,
      });

      await user.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400).send({ error: "Cannot reset password, try again" });
    }
```